# synonym for "introspection" or "thinking inwardly"

Tags: word-request, informal-language

I want to use a word that not only conveys the meaning of "thinking inwardly" but also is common, informal and normal in native English. I use the examples below and some synonyms for clarification, but please don't limit yourself to these ideas since I am not a native speaker, and inform me if you have opposite sentiments. Also, I'm looking for a "verb" as its equivalent.

> In the modern world, in which we are snowed under with countless tasks, almost every adult feels worn out and experiences burnout, and forgets to care for his mental health. Therefore, I hold this contention that we must devote some time to **think inwardly** about our emotional and mental problems.

There are also some other terms that I've heard, but there are some problems with each of them.

For being "common": I searched https://www.ludwig.guru and https://www.english-corpora.org. For being "professional", I used my own knowledge since I study psychology, and have only seen this word in old psychological texts.

"think intrinsically" is not common and usual.

"introspect" is rather uncommon and is used in professional contexts, but I am looking for an ordinary word that we can utilize in informal speaking, and our addressee understands easily.

Comment: What do you think about 'reflect on'?

Comment: Unless you are "thinking out loud", then thinking is always inward.  You could just say "think about".

Comment: Consider "ponder".  ("Snowed with" is not right. "Snowed in by" would be OK. I think both sentences are too wordy.)

Comment: @EthanBolker please check out this link: https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-snowed-under

Comment: @JMB it sounds great, but we would say, "reflect on our emotions and mental problems." what if I don't want to mention "emotions and mental problems"? Is there any equivalent in your view?

Comment: @CanadianYankee But, when we think about tasks we are struggling with in work we don't reflect on our mental problems or emotions.

Comment: @AliSirous I think we can say "reflect on our emotions and mental problems" but we can also reduce to "reflect on our mental health" or maybe more vaguely (but inside the context of your paragraph) "reflect on ourselves".

Comment: @AliSirous "Snowed under" or "snowed under with" but not plain "snowed with". You have to be under all that snow.

Comment: @AliSirous - Yes, but when you write "think about our mental problems and emotions," then that means thinking about one's own mental problems and emotions rather tautologically.

Comment: @EthanBolker what a gaffe! I refined it now Ethan. Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: @CanadianYankee if you mean we should omit "mental problems and emotions", I don't get along with your idea since then it is not clear what we are thinking about, and it seems vague.

Comment: No, I'm saying you should keep the "mental problems and emotions." What I'm saying is that the phrase "thinking about our mental problems and emotions" is essentially the definition of "introspection," so there's nothing wrong with using just that phrase.

Answer (score 1):

The first word that comes to my mind is "self-examination".

"Introspection" is not a word limited to professional psychologists. I've read it used by many real people :-). But yeah, it's rare enough that if you were writing something for the ordinary person off the street, many would not know what it means.

I think in general people use a phrase rather than a single word for this idea. They'll say things like, "You should examine your own feelings".

I don't recall hearing the phrase "think intrinsically" and my first impression wouldn't be that it is a synonym for introspection. How I'd interpret it would, I suppose, depend on context. Intrinsic to what?

Comment: I'm not sure how you would fit "self-examination" into the given sentence. The OP is asking for a verb, not a noun,  "I hold this contention that we must devote some time to ***think inwardly*** about our emotional and mental problems."

Comment: How about, "I hold this contention that we must devote some time to self-examination about our emotional and mental problems."

Comment: @Jay self-examination seems a good equivalent, yet chasly is right, I'm looking for a verb instead of it, and should have mentioned it in the question. I will refine my question now. Is there any other equivalent you can think of Jay?

Comment: I can't think of a single word that's a verb that is in common use. Maybe there's a word that's just not coming to mind, but I think you'd have to use a phrase, like "examining yourself". There are a lot of questions on this forum in the form "what is one word in English that means ...", and often the answer is, there is no "one word" that means that, you have to use a phrase.

Comment: @jay I see. I do agree with you. I myself don't look for words, and wait till something comes across me. Nonetheless, I use this meaning a lot and that is why I'm searching for the easiest way to convey it. Anyway, thank you very much, Jay.

Answer (score 0):

**Drawing from the comments**

we must devote some time to *reflect on* our emotional and mental problems

we must devote some time to *think about* our emotional and mental problems

we must devote some time to *ponder* our emotional and mental problems

**And some more**

we must devote some time to *contemplate* our emotional and mental problems

we must devote some time to *scrutinise* our emotional and mental problems

we must devote some time to *meditate on* our emotional and mental problems

**Recommendation**

***reflect on*** is very commonly used these days.

---

[image]